# How to change the index of a key in dict?

Tags: python, string, dictionary

I'm using Python 3.7 so dictionnaries are ordered.
I have a dict like this : `d = { 'a': 10, 'b': 20, 'c': 30}`.
I want to get : `d = { 'a': 10, 'c': 30, 'b': 20,}`.
I know I can get the index of a key with `d.index("a")`, but I didn't find a way to change the index.

Comment: dicts aren't ordered by their definition. Use a list if you *need* things ordered

Comment: You can use [OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) if the order of the keys is important to you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is to use d.items(). This will return a list [('a', 10), ('b', 20), ('c', 30)]. Lists can be easily rearranged however you want. Check out https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_list_sort.asp

Answer (score 0):

Try using `OrderedDict` from the `collections` library.
Then you can change the order of the keys by using the `move_to_end()` method and sort the dictionary however you'd like.

```
from collections import OrderedDict


data = OrderedDict({'a': 10, 'b': 20, 'c': 30})
print(data.keys())
# output: odict_keys(['a', 'b', 'c'])

data.move_to_end('b')
print(data.keys())
# output: odict_keys(['a', 'c', 'b'])
```

Answer (score -1):

You should try something like this!

```
d[newKey] = d[oldKey]
del d[oldKey]
```

If the key is undefined it will raise an error